# Create Widget Content in Page Builder

Tags: magento2.3.1, magento-enterprise-2, page-builder

I need to show in my home page a bestseller products list of certain category. To do so, i already created programmatically my own widget that lists bestseller products, but there's no way to drag a widget content with page builder. I know that i can drag a HTML content and insert there my widget, but i wonder if there's a better solution.

What's the best way to achieve it? Is there any way to extend Page Builder so i can add a widget type? Would you recommend any other option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The simplest is using the Text content type to include the widget using the standard TinyMCE widget feature.

Your other option is to create a new content type which wraps your widget in a Page Builder content type. Our Products content type does exactly this, it's just an interface for the Catalog Product List widget.

`products.xml` contains a mass converter to create the widget directive:

`view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/products.xml`

```xml
<converters>
    <converter component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/products/mass-converter/widget-directive" name="widget_directive">
        <config>
            <item name="html_variable" value="html"/>
        </config>
    </converter>
</converters>
```

Which in turn within `widget-directive.ts` (or JS depending on which source you're viewing) we create the standard product list widget directive:

`view/adminhtml/web/ts/js/content-type/products/mass-converter/widget-directive.ts`:

```js
    public toDom(data: ConverterDataInterface, config: ConverterConfigInterface): object {
        const attributes = {
            type: "Magento\\CatalogWidget\\Block\\Product\\ProductsList",
            template: "Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml",
            anchor_text: "",
            id_path: "",
            show_pager: 0,
            products_count: data.products_count,
            type_name: "Catalog Products List",
            conditions_encoded: this.encodeWysiwygCharacters(data.conditions_encoded || ""),
        };

        if (attributes.conditions_encoded.length === 0) {
            return data;
        }

        set(data, config.html_variable, this.buildDirective(attributes));
        return data;
    }
```

You can read more about mass converters here: https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/reference/configurations.html#mass-converter

You can look to duplicate the Products content type and modify it to your needs. On a high level, it just feeds it's configured form fields into the directive's parameters.

Alongside the above, we have a great step by step tutorial on how to create a new content type available here: https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/create-custom-content-type/overview.html

Comment: Can you share your module ?